# How do I position lines exactly in C#

Tags: c#, graphics

I do *NOT* want the system trying to scale my drawing, I want to do it entirely on my own as any attempt to squeeze/stretch the graphics will produce ugly results.  The problem is that as the image gets bigger I want to add more detail rather than have it simply scale up.

Right now I'm looking at two sets of stripes.  One is black/white, the other is black/white/white.  The pen width is set to 1.

When the line is drawn horizontally it's correct.  The same logic drawing vertical lines appears to be doing some antialiasing, bleeding the black onto the nearby white.  The black/white/white doesn't look as good as the horizontal, the black/white looks more like medium++ gray/medium-- gray.

The same code is generating the coordinates in all cases, the transform logic is simply selecting what offset to apply where as I am only supporting orientations on the cardinals.  Since there's no floating point involved I can't be looking at precision issues.

How do I get the system to leave my graphics alone???

(Yeah, I realize this won't work at very high resolution and eventually I'll have to scale up the lines.  Over any reasonable on-screen zoom factor this won't matter, for printer use I'll have to play with it and see where I need to scale.  The basic problem is that I'm trying to shoehorn things into too few pixels without just making blobs.)

**Edit:** There is no scaling going on.  I'm generating a bitmap the exact size of the target window.  All lines are drawn at integer coordinates.  The recommendation of setting SmoothingMode to None changes the situation:  Now the black/white/white draws as a very clear gray/gray/white and the black/white draws as a solid gray box.  Now that this is cleaned up I can see some individual vertical lines that were supposed to be black are actually doing the same thing of drawing as 2-pixel gray bars.  It's like all my vertical lines are off by 1/2 pixel--yet every drawing command gets only integers.

**Edit again:** I've learned more about the problem.  The image is being drawn correctly but trashed when displayed to the screen.  (Saving it to disk and viewing it on the very same monitor shows it drawn correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [System.Drawing.Drawing2d.SmoothingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9.aspx).  Setting it to 'Default' or 'None' should turn off anti aliasing when doing line drawing.  If you're talking about scaling an image without anti aliasing effects, have a look at [InterpolationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx).  Specifically, you might wish to set it to 'Nearest-Neighbor' which will keep your rectangular blocks perfectly crisp. Note that you *will* see some odd effects if you scale your image by anything other than whole numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You really should let the system manage it for you. You have described a certain behavior that is specific to the hardware you are using. Given different hardware, the problem may not exist at all, or it may exist horizontally but not vertically, or may only exist at much smaller or much larger resolutions, etc. etc.

The basic problem you described sounds like the vertical lines are being drawn "between" vertical stacks of pixels, which is causing the system to draw an anti-aliased line. The alternative to anti-aliasing the line is to shift it. The problem with that is the lines will "jitter" or "jerk" if the image is moved around, animated, or scaled or transformed in any other way. Generally, jerk is MUCH less desirable than anti-aliasing because it is more distracting.

You should be able to turn off anti-aliasing using the [SmoothingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9.aspx) enum, or you could try to handle positioning yourself. Either way, you are trading anti-aliasing for jittery, jerky rendering during any movement or transformation.

Comment: What do you mean by letting the system handle it for me?  I see no way it can--I'm trying to add more detail as the image gets bigger.  When the tiles are small the drawings are awfully crude but trying to do anything more detailed would just make a blob.

Comment: I am assuming you are using GDI+ in .NET. With GDI+ (and WPF if you are willing to use a more modern framework), you have the ability to use Transforms. You can draw your image as if it was a vector image, and scale, rotate, skew, and move it using transformations. The system will handle everything for you from that point, and all you need to do is apply the appropriate transformation to display the image you are trying to draw, or a part of it, in your viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to align your lines on half-pixel coordinates? A one pixel line drawn at say `x = 5` would be drawn on the center of the line, which means it would go from `x = 4.5` to `x = 5.5`. If you want it to go from `x = 4` to `x = 5` then you'd need to set its coordinate to `x = 4.5`.

GDI+ has a property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pixeloffsetmode.aspx that allows you to control this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to change your application to tell the system it is DPI aware so scaling doesn't occur. Here's an article on doing that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: That imports user32.dll and thus is non-portable.  Not exactly a good solution.

Comment: The automatic scaling issue is specific to Windows so a non-portable solution should be acceptable.